# Need to select Data from XML file C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

What I'm trying to do is get data from my XML file which has been merged with two others and selected each venue from that file and try to add the value to a list so I can manipulate it further.

This is one of my XML files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Funrun>
<Venue name="Roker Park">
<Runner charity="Cancer Research">
  <Firstname>Roger</Firstname>
  <Lastname>Malibu</Lastname>
  <Sponsorship>550</Sponsorship>
</Runner>
<Runner charity="Arthritis UK">
  <Firstname>Adam</Firstname>
  <Lastname>White</Lastname>
  <Sponsorship>340</Sponsorship>
</Runner>
</Venue>
</Funrun >
```

I need to be able to select the venue name and save it to a list. This is what I've got so far:

```
List<string> VenueNames = new List<string>();
var doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
var doc2 = XDocument.Load("XMLFile2.xml");
var doc3 = XDocument.Load("XMLFile3.xml");
var combinedUnique = doc.Descendants("Venue")
                  .Union(doc2.Descendants("Venue"))
                  .Union(doc3.Descendants("Venue"));

foreach (var venuename in combinedUnique.Elements("Venue"))
{
   VenueNames.Add(venuename.Attribute("name").Value));
}
```

Comment: And why doesn't this do what you want? other than there being better ways to write the above

Comment: Please clarify what is wrong with above code, what are you going to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> xmlFilePaths = new List<string>
{
    @"Path\\SomeJson.txt",
    @"Path\\SomeJson1.txt"
};

var venues = xmlFilePaths.Select(fp => XDocument.Load(fp).Descendants("Venue")?.FirstOrDefault()?.Attribute("name")?.Value).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I would do it is by including Name and Charity within the XElements they belong to.
What I would recommend you do is first reformat your document so that it looks like this:

```
<Funrun>
    <Venue>
        <Name>Roker Park</Name>
        <Runner1>
            <charity>Cancer Research</charity>
            <Firstname>Roger</Firstname>
            <Lastname>Malibu</Lastname>
            <Sponsorship>550</Sponsorship>
        </Runner1>
        <Runner2>
            <charity>Arthritis UK</charity>
            <Firstname>Adam</Firstname>
            <Lastname>White</Lastname>
            <Sponsorship>340</Sponsorship>
        </Runner2>
    </Venue>
</Funrun >
```

Note that you could get even simpler by combining all the elements under "Funrun" (example: "Venue") and just iterate through all of them without having to switch documents.

Next moving over to C#:

```
List<string> VenueNames = new List<string>();
var doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
var doc2 = XDocument.Load("XMLFile2.xml");
var doc3 = XDocument.Load("XMLFile3.xml");

foreach (XElement element in doc.Root.Descendants("Venue"))
        {
            VenueNames.Add(element.Element("Name").Value.ToString());
        }
//Copy paste this code for each document you would like to search through, though of course change "doc" to say, "doc2".
```

So just real quick, what this code will do is it will first open the Root element in the XDocument. It will find Decendants of that element with the name, "Name", and for each of those it will copy its value as a string into your list.

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you that works very nicely. But when I merge the files in the combined unique var it doesnt seem to accept Root, is there a way around this or would I have to do it how you have suggested?